# Use Ruby program. Input: sentence Modify: words Output: modified sentence

Tags: ruby, string

I am new to Ruby. This is a programming interview question to use any language. I am trying to do it in Ruby.

Write a program to input a given sentence. Replace each word with the firstletter/#ofcharactersbetween1st&lastletter/lastletter of the word. All non-alpha (numbers, punctuation, etc.) should not be changed.

Example input: There are 12 chickens for 2 roosters.

Desired output: T3e a1e 12 c6s f1r 2 r6s.

I have the concept but need help with better approach and how to put the parts together:

```
   s="There are 12 chickens for 2 roosters." 
.. 
=> "There are 12 chickens for 2 roosters."
   a = s.split(" ")
=> ["There", "are", "12", "chickens", "for", "2", "roosters."]
   puts a.length
7
=> nil
   puts a[0].length
5
=> nil
   puts a[0].length-2
3
=> nil
   puts a[0][0]
84
=> nil
   puts a[0][0].chr
T
=> nil
   puts a[0].length-2
3
=> nil
   puts a[0][-1].chr
e
=> nil
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
s = "There are 12 chickens for 2 roosters."
s.gsub(/([A-Za-z]+)/) { $1[0] + ($1.size - 2).to_s + $1[-1] }
```

It uses [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) which replaces all parts of the string matching the regular expression pattern.

The pattern in this case is `/([A-Za-z]+)/` and groups occurrences of one or more characters in the ranges A-Z and a-z.

`{ $1[0] + ($1.size - 2).to_s + $1[-1] }` is a block executed for every occurrence. `$1` is the first group matched in the pattern. The block replaces the occurrence with its first character `$1[0]`, its length -2 to string `($1.size - 2).to_s` and its last character `$1[-1]`.

Comment: Your example don't work if I copy and paste in irb. Plus, it don't consider words with size of one or two. Maybe you want to fix it?

Comment: @fotanus which version of ruby are you using?. It works with 1.9 and 2.0. 1.8.7 puts out the char code when a string index is used, but since  1.8.7 will be deprecated in june, I will not bother to provide a fix here. There are no rules given for words with 1 character in the question, so I won't include one in the answer.

Comment: I was using ruby 1.8.7, it is true it work for the others. Do as you feel it is right.